# R Constained Combination generation

Tags: r, algorithm, computer-science

Say I have an set of string:

```
x=c("a1","b2","c3","d4")
```

If I have a set of rules that must be met:

- if "a1" and "b2" are together in group, then "c3" cannot be in that group.
- if "d4" and "a1" are together in a group, then "b2" cannot be in that group.

I was wondering what sort of efficient algorithm are suitable for generating all combinations that meet those rules? What research or papers or anything talk about these type of constrained combination generation problems?

In the above problem, assume its `combn(x,3)`

Comment: What kind of combinations are you trying to generate? From length 1 to 4? Is c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a1") a possible combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about R, so I'll just address the theoretical aspect of this question.

First, the constraints are really boolean predicates of the form "a1 ^ b2 -> ¬c3" and so on. That means that all valid combinations can be represented by one [binary decision diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram), which can be created by taking each of the constraints and ANDing them together. In theory you might make an exponentially large BDD that way (that usually doesn't happen, but depends on the structure of the problem), but that would mean that you can't really list all combinations anyway, so it's probably not too bad.

For example the BDD generated for those two constraints would be (I think - not tested - just to give an idea)

[image: bdd]

But since this is really about a family of sets, a [ZDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-suppressed_decision_diagram) probably works even better. The difference, roughly, between a BDD and a ZDD is that a BDD compresses nodes that have equal sub-trees (in the total tree of all possibilities), while the ZDD compresses nodes where the solid edge (ie "set this variable to 1") goes to False. Both re-use equal sub-trees and thus form a DAG.

The ZDD of the example would be (again not tested)

[image: ZDD]

I find ZDDs a bit easier to manipulate in code, because any time a variable can be set, it will appear in the ZDD. In contrast, in a BDD, "skipped" nodes have to be detected, including "between the last node and the leaf", so for a BDD you have to keep track of your universe. For a ZDD, most operations are independent of the universe (except complement, which is rarely needed in the family-of-sets scenario). A downside is that you have to be aware of the universe when constructing the constraints, because they have to contain "don't care" paths for all the variables not mentioned in the constraint.

You can find more information about both BDDs and ZDDs in The Art of Computer Programming volume 4A, chapter 7.1.4, there is an old version available for free [here](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/).

These methods are in particular nice to represent large numbers of such combinations, and to manipulate them somehow before generating all the possibilities. So this will also work when there are many items and many constraints (such that the final count of combinations is not too large), (usually) without creating intermediate results of exponential size.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough response. I majored in Comp Sci and I understand most of what you say just that I've only read them in textbooks in my discrete math class, never applied it in real life. Are there any open source code for this? If not, I'll have to slave through this slowly ;) Have you implemented something similar?

Comment: @user1234440 CUDD is probably the most famous implementation, but I rolled my own BDD engine when I made [this site](http://haroldbot.cloudapp.net/), and my own ZDD engine to do some combinatorial stuff (Project Euler problems, and solving some weighted exact cover problems), CUDD could do all of that too of course but that's less fun :)